# dlclose() does not call the destructor of global objects

Tags: c++, dll, gcc, dlopen, atexit

plugin1.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

static class TestStatic {
public:
  TestStatic() {
     std::cout << "TestStatic create" << std::endl;
  }
  ~TestStatic() {
     std::cout << "TestStatic destroy" << std::endl;
  }
} test_static;
```

host.cpp

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
   void* handle = dlopen("./plugin1.so",RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL );
   dlclose(handle);
   return 0;
}
```

build and run:

```
>g++ -c plugin1.cpp -o plugin1.o -fPIC
>g++ -shared plugin.o -o plugin1.so
>g++ host.cpp -o host -ldl
>./host
>TestStatic create
>Segmentation fault
```

why TestStatic::~TestStatic called at 'exit()' but not at 'dlclose()' ?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://forum.soft32.com/linux2/dlclose-causing-segmentation-fault-exit-main-ftopict10002.html

Comment: option -fno-use-cxa-atexit for compilation plugin.cpp solve problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> The C++ Standard requires that destructors be called for global objects when a program exits in the opposite order of construction. Most implementations have handled this by calling the C library atexit routine to register the destructors. This is problematic because the 1999 C Standard only requires that the implementation support 32 registered functions, although most implementations support many more. More important, it does not deal at all with the ability in most implementations to remove DSOs from a running program image by calling dlclose prior to program termination.

This problem is addressed in later versions of GCC including C/C++ standard library and linker. Basically, C++ destructors should be registered using `__cxa_atexit` function instead of `atexit` (3).

For the full technical details on `__cxa_atexit`, see [Itanium C++ ABI specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

---

It is not clear from your question what version of the gcc, linker and standard C library you are using. Plus, the code you have provided does not meet [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard as there are no `RTDL_NOW` or `RTDL_LOCAL` macros defined. They are `RTLD_NOW` and `RTLD_LOCAL` (see [dlopen](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html)).

If your C standard library does not support `__cxa_atexit`, you may need to disable it by specifying `-fno-use-cxa-atexit` gcc flag:

> -fuse-cxa-atexit
>
> Register destructors for objects with static storage
>   duration with the __cxa_ atexit
>   function rather than the atexit
>   function. This option is required for
>   fully standards-compliant handling of
>   static destructors, but will only work
>   if your C library supports
>   __cxa_atexit.

But that might result in a problem where destructors are called in different order or not called at all. So the best solution in case of broken `__cxa_atexit` support or no support at all is not to use static objects with destructors in your shared libraries.