# How do you know whether main has exited?

Tags: c++, static, posix, program-entry-point, exit

In both C and C++, `atexit` functions are called either inside `exit`, or after `main` returns (which notionally calls `exit`: `__libc_start_main(argc,argv) { __libc_constructors(); exit(main(argc,argv)); }`).

Is there a way to find out if we're inside the exit sequence? Destructors of C++ global and local statics are registered with `atexit`, so your code can certainly be called into at this stage. (Interestingly, on some platforms if you try to create a C++ local-static object inside `exit`, it deadlocks on the exit lock!)

My best attempt so far is as follows:

```
static bool mainExited = false;
static void watchMain() {
  static struct MainWatcher {
    ~MainWatcher() { mainExited = true; }
  } watcher;
}
```

When you want to watch for exit, you call `watchMain()`, and `mainExited` tells you at any time whether or not the exit sequence has begun -- except of course if a later-initialized local-static object is destructing!

Can the technique be improved to correct this, or is there another method that would work?

#### Aside - the use case!

While the problem is interesting from a language point-of-view (a bit like "can I tell if I'm inside a `catch` block?"), it's also useful to outline a use-case. I came across the problem while writing some code which will be run with and without a JVM loaded (with either direct calls or calls via JNI). After the JVM exits, the C `atexit` handlers are called, and `JNI_OnUnload` is not called if the JNI shared library is not unloaded by the class loader.

Since the shared library's objects can be destructed both by explicit destruction (and should free their resources), and by cleanup at exit, I need to distinguish these two cases safely, since the JVM is gone by the time we reach the exit code! Basically without a bit of sniffing there's no way I can find in the JNI specs/docs for a shared library to know whether the JVM is still there or not, and if it's gone, then it's certainly wrong to try and free up references we have to Java objects.

Comment: Can you maybe explain the use-case for this?

Comment: Create an object in main which logs its destruction. If it's the first object created, its destructor will be the last function called before main returns.

Comment: @Benjamin I had in mind that objects created in `main` aren't destructed inside `exit`, only global and local statics? So are you suggesting to have a local static inside main -- in which case this is pretty much the same as my solution.

Comment: Why not have local non-static object in `main` to detect if you're leaving `main`?

Comment: If you need to know, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't have "Modern C++ Design" handy here, but Andrei Alexandrescu made a detailed analysis of this kind of post-main issues in his book.

Answer (score 7):

The real issue here is that the ownership semantics you've listed are messed up. The JVM kinda owns your shared library but also kinda doesn't. You have a bunch of references to Java objects that sometimes you need to clean up but sometimes you don't.

The real solution here is simply to not keep references to Java objects as global variables. Then you won't need to know if the JVM still exists or not when the library is unloaded for whatever reason. Just keep references to Java objects from inside objects referenced by Java and then let the JVM care about whether or not it needs to free them.

In other words, don't make yourself responsible for cleanup on exit in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your watcher doesn't need to rely on any static initialization order:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MainWatcher  // : boost::noncopyable
{
    enum MainStatus { before, during, after };

    MainWatcher(MainStatus &b): flag(b) { flag = during; }
    ~MainWatcher() { flag = after; }
    MainStatus &flag;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Test suite
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// note: static data area is zero-initialized before static objects constructed
MainWatcher::MainStatus main_flag;

char const *main_word()
{
    switch(main_flag)
    {
        case MainWatcher::before: return "before main()";
        case MainWatcher::during: return "during main()";
        case MainWatcher::after: return "after main()";
        default: return "(error)";
    }
}

struct Test
{
    Test()  { std::cout << "Test created "   << main_word() << "\n"; }
    ~Test() { std::cout << "Test destroyed " << main_word() << "\n"; }
};

Test t1;

int main()
{
    MainWatcher watcher(main_flag);

    // rest of code
    Test t2;
}
```

Comment: Nice try, but what about if `exit` is called? You're right though that, if you can modify main, then it's possible to detect main's exit before all destructors of statics are called.

Comment: If the `exit` function is called then the program is considered to terminate without `main` returning.  Your title could be read in two ways; did you mean "How do you know if main has returned?", or "How do you know if an `atexit` handler has been executed?"  (or something else again - there are ways to terminate the program without running atexit handlers?)

Comment: Note that in general, static  destructors are not required to use the `atexit` mechanism

Comment: There do seem to be [some issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810157/dlclose-does-not-call-the-destructor-of-global-objects) surrounding gcc, and destructors of static objects in a shared library.

Comment: For all the six Unix platforms I have to support, static destructors are supported fine by libc -- the poster in that question is using an unspecified platform and probably doing something weird. On linux and OS X certainly, there are no issues with destructors of static objects.

I'm sorry the title is a bit ambiguous; the first paragraphs state the problem clearly though: "Is there a way to find out if we're inside the exit sequence?"

Comment: @NicholasWilson define "the exit sequence"?